# How to enforce Joomla password policy when users reset passwords

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I've set a Joomla site password policy via users > options.

If I add a new user via the backend and try to set an insecure password, the policy seems to work and I get the appropriate error message.

If the user logs in, goes to their profile and changes their password, the password policy is still enforced.

However, if the user goes to the login screen, chooses 'Forgot your password' they are able to choose a new password which **doesn't pass** the policy.

I'm using the default Joomla login and registration extensions and as far as I can see, there's nothing else that could be causeing a conflict.

Does anyone have some suggestions on where to look?

**EDIT**
Site is using Joomla! 3.3.6 Stable, which is currently the latest version of Joomla

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exact version of Joomla are you using, I'll see if I can identify the cause and as this question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hi @cppl, I'm using Joomla! 3.3.6 Stable, and yes your suggestion of asking the Joomla Q&A is good, thanks!